# How to redirect to a controller in Grails while passing a parameter

Tags: grails

I have 2 actions in my controller

```
def listGame(){
   def category = GameCategory.list()
   def currentCategory = params.categoryName
   def myCategory=GameCategory.findByCategoryName(currentCategory)
   def games = myCategory.games

   [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, games:games]

}
def listGameByPlatform(){
   def platform = params.platform 
   redirect(view: "listGame")
}
```

I only access the listGameByPlatform when I click a certain button that's why it is separated

I have listGame.gsp but I dont have a listGameByPlatform.gsp so I want to redirect my listGameByPlatform action to listGame but I also want to pass the platform as parameter to listGame.gsp, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, just add `parameters: [platform: platform]` in there
please refer to [this page](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html)

```
def listGameByPlatform(){
   def platform = params.platform 
   redirect(view: "listGame", parameters: [platform: platform])
 }
```

you can also just pass all the params through: `parameters: params` if you want to save a step.
Then to add it to the `gsp`  you'll just need to add it to the map in the action:

```
 [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, games:games, platform: params.platform]
```

Comment: I don't need to change anything on my listGame action so that my listGame.gsp can access platform?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that part, ya I'll update my answer.

Comment: Got an error saying "Cannot get property 'games' on null object" Highlighting  def games = myCategory.games    



This is my code in my view
<g:link action="listGameByPlatform" params="${[currentCategory: "${currentCategory}", platform:"${platforms.platformName}"]}"

Comment: that's because you don't have anything called platforms...   you have the params.platform object there, that you can pass to your gsp, but likely it's just a string...  So I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have something called platforms in my code now. I added def platform = Platform.list() in my listGame action 
 [currentCategory:currentCategory, category:category, games:games, platforms:platform]